Write mixed effect model
This is a statisical and R question: I am trying to compare two sampling methods for sampling invertebrates.  Both methods were used at upstream and downstream of wastewater inputs. Environmental factors measured at both upstream and downstream.
My questions:

Are there differences (in several metrics) between the sampling methods?
Are these differences greater (or lower) at the downstream site?
How do environmental factors affect these differences? (i.e., do sites with worse environments have greater differences?)

I ran the pairwise_t_test routine in the rstatix program. And answered question 1.
But I think I need to run a more complex model for questions 2. and 3. And potentially use AIC to help determine the best model.
I will be conducting this analyses in R.
And I am stumped by this.
Any help would be appreciated.

The statistical aspects of the question may be better suited for Cross Validated. However, to make it easier to get help, please describe the experiment and the data in detail: how is the data is collected, what do the covariates represent, what is the outcome variable and how is it measured.... If you can include (a sample of) the data, all the better.
